# Point the sqlite path to defautl app path .

Tags: codenameone

In Ubuntu 16.04 points the default db path to /home/username/.cn1/database/ instead of /home/username/workspace/ProjectName/src/ .

How to point the default app db path to /home/username/workspace/ProjectName/src/  ?

Answer (score 0):

That is the source directory whose content is compiled to produce the app. The source directory isn't on the device so that path wouldn't make sense on runtime where only the compiled app exists in a location that varies based on the device.

I'm assuming that what you are "really" after is to ship your app with a default sqlite database. This is discussed in the [SQL section of the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html#_sql):

> Some SQLite apps ship with a "ready made" database. We allow you to
>   replace the DB file by using the code:
>
> `String path = Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath(“databaseName”);`
>
> You can then use the FileSystemStorage class to write the content of
>   your DB file into the path. Notice that it must be a valid SQLite
>   file!

Comment: I agree that this directory doesn’t belong to the device, but this is the path returned by “Display.getInstance().getDatabasePath("MyDB.db")” while the sqlite file is located under /codename-path/src/  What’s wrong here?

Comment: The path returned from that API is the correct one. You need to copy the file from the `getResources` to the new location. There is sample code of this in https://github.com/codenameone/SQLSample/ just search for getDatabasePath